# Laravel 5.2: Can variable be classified in view?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2.
My question is:
Can variable be classified in view?

For example:
There is a controller ,it can get  all of the articles belonging to the current user, like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $user=\Auth::user();
    $articles = $user->articles;

    return view('user.dashboard.index',  compact('articles'));
}
```

In view,these codes below can show the articles,like this:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        Articles
    </div>
    @if ($articles!=null)
    <table class="table table-sm">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>created time</th>
            <th>status</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach ($articles as $article)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$article->title}}</td>
            <td>{{$article->created_at}}</td>
            <td>{{$article->status}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    @else
    <p>Nothing</p>
    @endif
</div>
```

These articles can be classified into two types:
1、“published”，status is `1`.
2、“unpublished”，status is `0`.

**Question：**
I would want the published articles to be shown in a card(div class="card"), and, the unpublished articles to be shown in another card.
Can they be classified in view? Thus,it doesn't need to query twice.

Comment: Why not just test the `status` inside your `foreach` loop? Something like `@if ($article->status === 1) { 'published card' } @else { 'unpublished card' } @endif`.

Comment: Can you explain some more what you mean with a card?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use collection method [where()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-where)

```
@foreach ($articles->where('published', 1)->all() as $article)
```

Just change `published` and `1` to real ones.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that isn't going to work. I think `->all()` should be `->get()`

Comment: @Slence, this example is from official documentation (click link inside my answer).

Comment: *The all method simply returns the underlying array represented by the collection* -  https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-all

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin That's for collections. With QueryBuilder/Eloquent, it's `get()`. `all()` is for queries returning every single row of the database.

Comment: @aynber, just checked this in TInker, `all()` works and returns an array.

Comment: In this case `$articles` is a collection so it works out.